# Adding a note to a favourite

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, bookmarks

I quite often add a question as a favourite when there is something of interest to me in it or its answers. Looking back through my favourites, I cannot remember why I added some of them as a favourite.

What I'd like to be able to do is to add a note/comment when I add a favourite as a reminder as to why I've added it. This will show on my favourites page, but nowhere else - and possibly to no one else.

In addition, it would be good to be able to favourite an answer to a question, thereby adding a favourite to both the question and a particular answer with something of note in it. This would only show as a single favourite, but when clicking its link would go to the favourited answer.

Possible? Or is there another way of doing this? I've already got too many favourites to remember why I added a lot of them.

Comment: Nice idea there.

Comment: Great idea.  I'd also like to be able to order my favorites as well - some hierarchy or classification for later lookup.

Comment: I'd like to be able to search within my favourites, because I have the opposite problem - I know I've favourited something, but I have to hunt through several pages of favourites to find it.  (Note that I'm talking about a full search, not just titles and tags.)

Comment: I would prefer the full search ability that Richie mentioned, but the note option would be nice as well.

Comment: @tim: maybe something like `tags`?

Comment: See my answer over [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251234/260841).

Comment: In the meantime, there is a feature called [saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/saves/info). For each saved post you can add a note up to 500 characters. Currently both saves and the notes are private - see [this related feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391888).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a good idea. If it doesn't make it to StackOverflow, you could try bookmarking the favourites in [del.icio.us](http://del.icio.us), and adding notes there. If you tag them all with SOfave or something, then they'll be grouped together, and you could sub-divide them with other tags.

Comment: Good work around, delicious is more searchable then SO favorites.

Comment: I currently use google bookmarks to do this same thing, but I'd like it to be part of SO really so as to keep my SO favourites within the scope of SO.

Comment: @JamesMcMahon Favorites are now searchable with `infavorites:mine`.