# Favorites improvements - search, categorize, personal tags, add note, favorite answer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bookmarks

I'm a big fan of the favorites feature. I usually mark questions with good answers of code snippets for later use.

Most of the time I can't find the favorite I'm looking for so quickly as desired. I know I marked the question in Stack Overflow, but it takes time to find it again, because of the following reasons:

- lot of favorites
- lot of answers for a question (last time I was looking for an answer in the question [Hidden Features of C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c))
- the question title is not always what I'm looking for

To make favorites more useful I suggest the following features to be added:

- Allow to mark an answer as favorite
- Allow to tag questions with own tags (those tags are personal and can not be seen by others)
- Search function over favorites
- Allow to add a personal note to a question

Comment: You can always just bookmark the answer - it has it's own "link" link.

Comment: @ChrisF that's true, but i would be more handy to have it right inside StackOverflow rather than managing bookmarks in the browser. a lot of favorites i mark at home and use it at work. and as my company blocks almost everything i can't even use bookmarking tools like del.ico.us and co.

Comment: I was going to add that, perhaps I should have.

Comment: *Search function over favorites* — see `infavorites:mine` at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: *Allow to add personal note to a question* — see Diigo at [Any tool to help reviewing a website (snapshots, annotations, feedback)?](http://superuser.com/questions/220045/any-tool-to-help-reviewing-a-website-snapshots-annotations-feedback)

Comment: even a filter box for favorite titles would be a great advancement

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/detail-recent-favorite-changes, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83286/can-more-of-the-functionality-of-the-old-envelope-be-added-to-the-new-drop-down-m

Comment: @gsharp, see my answer for a workaround to the problem... it will lag your favorites for up to a month, but it is better than nothing.

Comment: @gsharp In addition to everything that everyone mentioned here, (which is awesome btw and should be implemented ASAP) I would also love to see the ability of adding my favorites into custom defined lists. For example, I can add two of my favorite STL questions to a custom list which I would name "Questions regarding STL". My suggestion is very similar to the 'Circles' feature in Google+ and 'Custom friend list' feature on Facebook.

Comment: @ChosenTorture unfortunately my post is over 2 years old and nothing has do be done so far. I guess it's not in the priority list of the SE team.

Comment: I think that personal tags or notes would be the solution to another request as well. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/notify-us-when-the-question-has-been-edited-after-posting-an-answer

Comment: @ChrisF *You can always just bookmark the answer*. Yes, but favorites get highlighted when there is new activity, and regular bookmarks don't.

Comment: Sorry to necro this, @ChrisF, but I would really love to have more ways of organizing my currently 1263 favorite/bookmarked questions in Math.SE. At least by tags, so I can find them when looking for material for my courses :-)

Comment: This was recently announced - it seems to be in the spirit of this feature request: [Bookmarks Are Evolving Into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [All (or some) of my bookmarks or saved posts seem to have disappeared! What happened?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382588/all-or-some-of-my-bookmarks-or-saved-posts-seem-to-have-disappeared-what-happ) - Using Sonic's canonical.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Allow me to throw my hat in the ring with a mockup of this feature that I too would very much like to see implemented.

Consider using different colored stars<sup>1</sup> for various user-defined categories ("tags").

### Favoriting:

[image: favoriting mockup]

### Viewing Favorites:

[image: viewing favorites mockup]

The biggest issue I see with this is the major overhaul it would require. To get around that, I would suggest a "default" category where all favorites land in implementations not yet supported (mobile, apps, API, etc.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Rainbow stars make me think of unicorns, so this can't be a bad idea, can it?

Comment: I don't see same capability in unix.stackexchange.com, did you write an extenstion for firefox? how i use above capability?

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh I sure wish! This is just a photoshop mockup though. Some day, one can hope, they'll implement something like this

Comment: +1 - I've used this idea and default options in [my userscript](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251234/260841) - hope you don't mind :)

Comment: This feature is exactly what I would like: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324372/336030

Answer (score 43):

I frequently use favorites for multiple purposes as well, and everything gets jumbled together.

I really like the personal tags idea.

1. The tags would aid in searching through you favorites.
2. It allows personal notes about a question
3. It would allow users like myself to categorize favorites into things like 'Check back for edit/reply to my comment', 'Look at implementing in the future', etc.
4. It could be a work around for tagging an answer as a favorite.

I recommend implementing at least this addition.

Comment: I think this would be the solution to another request as well. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/notify-us-when-the-question-has-been-edited-after-posting-an-answer

Answer (score 17):

Having a full-text (both question and answer) search box at the top of your favorites page is quite useful... the search should be local to your own favorites.  Perhaps this would be easier to implement than a local-tags feature, which (I predict) would require modification to the db schema.  If devs don't want to modify the favorites page, perhaps we could denote a full-text search of our own favorites by typing `favorites:` in the SO search bar.

<strike>I don't know why `infavorites:` was deleted from the new search capabilities introduced in January, but this functionality leaves a big gap when you have hundreds or thousands of favorites and you only want to find answers relevant to [foo](/questions/tagged/foo)</strike>

FWIW, I am hacking around the problem right now with:

- [**Stack Exchange Data Explorer Favorites query by tag name**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2264/list-of-favorites-for-a-userid-tagged-with-tagname)
- [**Stack Exchange Data Explorer Favorites query full-text search**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2266/list-of-favorites-for-a-userid-containing-some-text)

**EDIT NOTE**

`infavorites:mine` works again, but it only searches the title of the favorite.

Comment: This is great to be able to search through existing tags, title, and content. However, it covers only one of the requests. And it would be great if there was some kind of shortcut to this feature from the favorites tab.

Answer (score 7):

The favorite feature is useful and a token of any good Q&A site and you definitely point out some good improvements for it. I really like the concept of a personal note, because often times I will favorite a question when working on a specific project, because I know I'll want to reference it later. The personal note would allow me to write down exactly what I thought its significance was at the time.

I think the feature of having favorite answers would be the most significant change though. Most of my favorites are in fact favorite answers, and quite frankly I could care less about some of the questions. I think that the favorite answers and questions could be listed separately, but the user might be able to place questions in categories together  with answers, much like you were suggesting with the personal tags.

I think these suggestions would really benefit that So community. Just my thoughts.

Answer (score 6):

I really like the favorites feature too. But it's hard to manage when they are large.

Personal notes is a good idea, especially if **it allows personal notes about a question**.

Because for me

- track this question and its new answer
- store code
- just like

I suggest the feature can use **more tags (signs)** substitute for **star**.

Answer (score 6):

I've made a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6215/favourites-enhancer-tag-favourites-and-add-personal-notes) to do some of the suggestions you mention, which are:

- add personal notes to favourites
- add tags (or 'categories') to favourites

Here's a gif:

[image]

Get it at [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/6215/favourites-enhancer-tag-favourites-and-add-personal-notes).

Answer (score 4):

*[edit] I finally found out about the "infavorites:" tag in "search". The following could be a UI improvement, but the functionnality already exists. [/edit]*

My 2 cents :

I totally back the "add user based data (tags, private notes) to favorite questions".

Here are two other suggestions, which IMHO would note require as much back-end development :

- add a tag filter : gather the list of tags represented in the favorite questions, present them as clickable buttons on the right hand side, much like "favorite tags" filter for questions ;
- add a keyword filter : have an input on top of list, typing words in it will look for this word either in tags, or question's title.

Provided there is a way to get all the favorite questions info (title + tags) in one query, this could be implemented writing client side code only.