# How can I query SEDE for Favorites tagged with <foo>

Tags: support, bookmarks, data-explorer

Since [we currently don't have a way to search our favorites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75944/favorites-improvements#87730), I built a SEDE Query to [List of Favorites for a UserId that are Tagged with TagName](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2264/list-of-favorites-for-a-userid-tagged-with-tagname).

The query takes two inputs:

- UserId (int)
- TagName (varchar)

However, I'm having problems doing a substring search on TagName within `Posts.Tags`.

```
SELECT Posts.id as [Post Link], Posts.Tags as [Tagged With]

FROM Votes, Posts

WHERE
     (Votes.PostId=Posts.Id) AND
     (Votes.VoteTypeId = 5) AND
     (Votes.UserId=##User:int##) AND
     ('##TagName##' LIKE Posts.Tags);
```

If a question tagged [python](/questions/tagged/python)[xml](/questions/tagged/xml), `Posts.Tags` contains a string like this: `<python><xml>`.

No matter what I try for values of `##TagName##`, I can only find questions with a single tag (see screenshot)...

[image: Single-tag favorites]

I have tried queries with the following `TagName` inputs:

- `<python>` (returns favorites that have a single tag: python)
- `%<python>%` (returns nothing)
- `%python%` (returns nothing)

Perhaps I have misunderstood the format of the source, but I haven't figured out a better way to make the `TagName` queries.  There are a lot of questions with multiple tags, but unless we have a wildcard (or substring) search capability on `Posts.Tags`, I'm not sure how we can get the right information.

Should I be able to do a wildcard search on `Posts.Tags` in SEDE?  If so, how should I modify my existing query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I almost feel like this should have been a question on SO since its a problem with your SQL not Data.SE

Basically you've got your like clause backwards

Try

```
SELECT Posts.id as [Post Link], Posts.Tags as [Tagged With]

FROM Votes, Posts

WHERE
     (Votes.PostId=Posts.Id) AND
     (Votes.VoteTypeId = 5) AND
     (Votes.UserId=##User:int##) AND
     (Posts.Tags like '%##TagName##%' );​
```

Another approach is to use the denormalized tags table and not use the like clause at all if you just want question tagged with at least the [python](/questions/tagged/python) as opposed to questions that have a tag that contains the word python (e.g. [ironpython](/questions/tagged/ironpython) [python3.x](/questions/tagged/python3.x))

```
SELECT p.id as [Post Link], p.Tags as [Tagged With]
FROM  
        Votes v
        INNER JOIN Posts p
        ON v.PostID = p.id
        INNER JOIN PostTags pt
        ON p.id = pt.PostId
        INNER JOIN tags t
        on pt.TagID = t.ID
WHERE
     v.VoteTypeId = 5 AND
     v.UserId=##User:int## AND
     t.TagName = '##TagName##' ;​ --Only those tagged with Python (so ironPython will be ignored)
```

Comment: That was it, thank you!  Perhaps I should have posted on Stack Overflow, but I did not know enough SQL to realize that it was my query instead of a functionality gap in SEDE