# How can I speed up this Data Explorer query?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I have the following [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/67422/72991/level-of-effort) query which attempts to compute the number of characters per reputation sorted in descending order for each user. Think of it as a silly level of effort metric. Who typed the most number of characters for each reputation point earned? Just a fun little comparison.

```
select top 10    /* 100 would be better */
    u.Id,
    u.DisplayName,
    min(u.Reputation) as Reputation,
    sum(len(p.Body)) as TotalLength,
    count(*) as TotalPosts,
    avg(len(p.Body)) as AvgPostLength,
    (cast(sum(len(p.Body)) as float) / cast(min(u.Reputation) as float)) as PostLengthPerReputation
from
    Posts p
    inner join Users u ON u.Id = p.OwnerUserId
where
    u.Reputation > 100000   /* 1000 would be better */
group by
    u.Id, u.DisplayName
order by
    PostLengthPerReputation desc
```

The problem is that I would like to do a top 10 (or even 100) for users above say 10,000 or even 1,000 reputation, but the query will timeout. I did get it to return for users with reputation > 100,000, but that is not very interesting. Anyone have any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: Huh? That's on topic on Stack Overflow _and_ Meta Stack Overflow! There should be a badge for that...

Comment: Ugggh.... **don't use float for math like this!!**

Comment: Depending on the plan you're getting, putting the contents of the where clause into the join might nudge the optimiser into a more efficient plan.  Of course, I don't think you can actually get a query plan from data.so ;-)

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells There is an "Include execution plan" checkbox on there, actually.

Comment: @JNK: Oh really? Why not? Is there a better way?

Comment: @BrianGideon It runs for me (without timing out) with CorncernedOfTurnbridgeWells suggestion of moving the WHERE clause into the JOIN.  [Here is a revised version](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67425/level-of-effort).

Comment: @jadamel27 - that's useful.  I never noticed it before.  However the stats I was doing mostly came from dba.se, so the volumes weren't terribly great.

Comment: @jadarnel27: Yeah, I just did the same thing and got it to work. But, now it's being really spotty again :(

Comment: Wow, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/117700/i) guy had to type 875 characters for each rep point.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast Ooh can we get SO rep on [a question like that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115785/)

Comment: @BrianGideon on the opposite side [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/268413/lfx-cool) got more than an **100 rep points per character** [See how you rank here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67437/level-of-effort-rank)

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: Ooo...that's cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments [Jardanel27](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/168428/jadarnel27) forked the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67425/level-of-effort) and moved the WHERE into the join, as suggested by [ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/15401/concernedoftunbridgewells)

```
SELECT TOP 100
    u.Id AS [User Link],
    min(u.Reputation) as Reputation,
    sum(len(p.Body)) as TotalLength,
    count(*) as TotalPosts,
    avg(len(p.Body)) as AvgPostLength,
    (cast(sum(len(p.Body)) as float) / cast(min(u.Reputation) as float)) as PostLengthPerReputation
FROM
    Posts p
    INNER JOIN Users u ON u.Id = p.OwnerUserId
    AND u.Reputation > 1000
GROUP BY
    u.Id
ORDER BY
    PostLengthPerReputation DESC
```