# Favorites count mismatch

Tags: support, stack-overflow, data-explorer, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why are my SEDE results inaccurate/obsolete/incorrect/outdated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130856/why-are-my-sede-results-inaccurate-obsolete-incorrect-outdated)

There is a mismatch between the favorites count reported on my [SO user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145682/deostroll) and on the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/75641/my-favourites-count).

I got the query for getting the favorites from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115776/135246) - I modified it a bit though. Is the query I've typed correct?

```
SELECT count(*) as [Favorites Count]

FROM Votes, Posts

WHERE
     (Votes.PostId=Posts.Id) AND
     (Votes.VoteTypeId = 5) AND
     (Votes.UserId=@userid)
     
Select DisplayName, Id
from Users 
where Id = @userid
```

Also checked it against other users, and still got the mismatch.

Answer (score 4):

You know that Data Explorer is not up-to-the-minute, right? There are only dumps periodically.

From http://www.clearbits.net/feeds/creator/146-stack-overflow-data-dump.rss

> released every 3 months
>   ...
>   <pubDate>Wed, 30 May 2012 17:38:15 +0000</pubDate>

Comment: According to [the other answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130857/165455) it's every 2 months, but if you want data more current than that, use the API.