# Keep a collection of questions I'm interested in

Tags: support, bookmarks, favorites-tab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Browsing around these sites I've stumbled upon questions that I found specially interesting (questions that I'd like to go back and try my hand at solving later, particularly suprising techniques, or that look interesting to include in a suggested set for self-study, whatever). So it would be nice to have a way to organize them in your profile. Note that this doesn't mean I'm in any way involved right now (either asking, commenting, editing) with the question.

Comment: Are you familiar with the favorite star on the left hand side?

Comment: [How do favorite questions work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click the star underneath the vote buttons then it will mark that question as a `favorite` of yours.  You can then go into your profile, click on the favorites tab, and see the list of them.  It will also highlight there which ones have changed since you were last looking at the list.

Comment: Thanks, that is a large part of what I'm looking for. What I'm really asking is if there is a way to clasify favorites into my own categories.

Comment: Nope, but that has been asked, I'll try and find that request for you.

Comment: @vonbrand, Here's [one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75944/favorites-improvements), though it's a little broad covering more than one thing, so it doesn't make a good feature request.