# Categorising favourite questions

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

When I favourite a question, it may be for a number of reasons. For example:

- One or more answers were (very) helpful, and I would like to reference them later.
- It *may* be an interesting read/answer, but don't have time now.
- It's an interesting newly posted question with no answers yet, but I'd like to see what answers will be provided.
- It's an interesting question and I *may* be able to provide an answer, but don't have the time to write one.
- I suspect that one of the answers may be wrong or needs improvement, but don't have time to investigate.
- It's a canonical question I often link to when explaining something or marking something as a duplicate.
- ... perhaps more ...

Unfortunately, they're are lobbed together in one big list, which is not very easy to navigate. In fact, it's a real pain to navigate.

There are a number of things that could be improved, but the easiest way with the largest gains is to **allow assigning a category or tag to a favourite question**.

Just one category per question would be fine; for all I care, they don't even have to be named by every individual user, having 10 pre-made categories named "1" to "10" and/or coloured would already be good enough IMHO and already a large improvement over the current situation.

---

There is a [related question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75944/favorites-improvements-search-categorize-personal-tags-add-note-favorite-a?s=2|4.8654) from 4 years ago, but that's a whole wish-list of feature requests, this is a more specific feature request.  That question does include an [answer with nice mockups](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225028/166789).

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce I came across that question in my searches, but as I understand it, it's asking for something different (adding a private note or comment to a favourite question).

Comment: See my answer over [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251234/260841).