# Categories and Groups for the "Favorites" tab

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bookmarks, favorites-tab

Now that my list of "Favorite" questions has spilled onto a second page, I have run into a problem.

I cannot see all my Favorites in a single glance. In addition, because of the large volume, I often cannot remember why I marked some of these as favorites to begin with.

It would be helpful to be able to **enter a short text description for each favorite question**.

This could be a nice, simple multipurpose solution:

- When reviewing or tracking changes, could use something like **"REVIEW"**
- When trying to remember to go back to a long Q/A, could use something like **"READ LATER"**
- When doing research on the topic of RDP command line parameters, could use something like **"RDP Project"**

Descriptions would be left blank initially, and users can continue to mark a favorite question with a single click. Descriptions could be edited later on the "Favorites" tab.

Currently, Favorites can be sorted by "votes", "recent", "newest", and "added". An additional option to sort by "description" would also be necessary.

---

#### Update

The answers received so far have been helpful, but I am looking for more than simple search. I would like the ability to tag each Favorite with the reason I saved it as a Favorite in the first place. The reason for selection is usually my own, and is often not found as text anywhere in the Q/A.

The current UI is lacking this feature, and I have found myself keeping a list of "Favorites" in a text file on my computer. This is rather inconvenient, as I access SE from several computers throughout the week.

Comment: Another related feature request: [Favorites improvements - search, categorize, personal tags, add note, favorite answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75944). And several of the [questions linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/75944) touch on the same (or at least similar) topic.

Comment: Note: [the Bookmarks feature (the renamed version of Favorites) was replaced with the Saves feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/335251), which does allow multiple customizable lists. As such, I'm closing this as no longer reproducible; since Saves is technically a different feature, I'm not marking it as [status-completed].

Comment: Nice! Just tried out Saves for the first time, and looks like a Big W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The features you're looking for are well-handled by your favorite web browser bookmarks (or "Favorites", if you prefer). Most browsers can synchronize across several computers, too.

This just looks like an overcomplication of a feature that's meant to be simple.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the search syntax `infavorites:mine` in this case.

Plug that in to the search bar with your search term, bingo, you're searching only your favorites.

For example, if you were to plug in `this sucks infavorites:mine`, you'll come up with [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) as one/your only result.