# Proposal for an "answerable by me" button

Tags: feature-request, questions, bookmarks

I'm mainly a TeX.SE user.

Since I have not much time to answer, I usually mark the answerable (by me) questions as favorite and when I have time, if nobody else already answered, I do it.

But with this way, I cannot discern the answerable posts from the ones which are actually my favorites.

Is there a chance to create another option other than the favorite star?

*Edit (reply to [nicael's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324378/336030)):* Instead of creating a new button, we could leave only the star, but with the chance of choosing, for example, its color. So I can mark my favorite with a gold star, the one I could answer with a green star, the one I like the most with a red star, and so on.

Comment: Related: [Favorites improvements - search, categorize, personal tags, add note, favorite answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75944)

Comment: @Bookends This answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225028/336030 is exactly what I would like!

Comment: FWIW, I've made a [userscript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251234/260841) that lets you tag posts with different names and comments if you want to give it a shot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually, a new feature was implemented that does what I like: [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network).

Now I can use "Bookmarks" for my useful posts and "Following" for the posts I can answer when I have time to!

Unfortunately, I noticed the existence of this new feature only more than a year after its implementation, they should have advertised it a bit more.

Comment: Well, just check [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/announcements?tab=Active) from time to time, it lists the network announcements, sorted by last activity. Any new feature like the Follow should be there.

Answer (score 9):

Why not just bookmark the questions you want to come back to?  It sounds like you don't need to keep a link to these questions for very long (you said you'd come back and answer if nobody else already did), so you could bookmark them, then delete the bookmarks once you answer or decide you're not going to.

Comment: It depends on what browser you're using, in Chrome you click the little star on the right-hand side of the address bar.

Comment: Ah, OK, you intended to mark them as favorites in my browser, sorry for not having caught it at once, language barriers. Yes, that could be a solution but I would prefer a StackExchange one.

Comment: it's more of a workaround, not a solution...

Comment: This workaround will also benefit people active on multiple sites, giving them a single list of "I will answer this as soon as I can" bookmarks in one place — while the favorites managed by SE are per site.

Comment: This will not work for users of the SE mobile app.

Answer (score 5):

For the (iOS) mobile app, here’s a solution: just tap the “add an answer” button and write *something*. You will be able to see the first few lines of what you wrote when you look at your drafts. Tap “cancel” and save the draft. (Or just leave a stack of answer drafts at the bottom of the screen...)

You will be able to see all your “drafts” by going to the hamburger menu (≡) on the left or swiping, and tapping “drafts”.

I have drafts that are 6 months old saved this way, so I don’t think they get deleted. And you can still favorite things on the app too.

(Un)fortunately, I don’t use the Android app so I’m not sure if this would work there.

If you’re using a browser, the way to go is bookmarks.

Comment: I have Android. However, +1, this can be helpful to someone else, thank you!

Comment: This answer would be great if the app was more useable and still maintained. It’s not. I still use the app to notify me of replies, but I never open it any more. The web app is soooo much better!

Answer (score 1):

There should be a real reason to implement something which in fact is another bookmarking option

There’s no such a reason.

Some funny examples for you, that idea could be extended to something like

- let’s make an additional option to mark a question as favorite since there could be an answer I’m interested in
- let’s make an additional option to mark a question as favorite so as not to forget to place a bounty
- let’s make an additional bookmarking option for th questions I was going to edit but didn’t have time
- let’s have a MOST FAVORITE option so as the questions marked with this option go to another list

Endless list! in a matter of fact, you could add another more-or-less ridiculous points here

Comment: A way to solve this problem could be creating a sort of categorized favorites, for example in MS Outlook you can assign a color to an e-mail, which represents a category. The button is only one (the star) but you could choose which color your star should have.