# feature Request: ability to add an ultra-pithy 'why I'm adding this' note-to-self as I click on a star to 'favorite-it'

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a note to a favourite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8619/adding-a-note-to-a-favourite)

As I click on a 'star' would ***really*** love the ability to be able to add a quick note on 'why-I'm-clicking-as-a-favorite'

---

***Author's add-on note*** -- if what I wrote was simplified to the "one-liner" just above, I would I concur that it's a 'duplicate' of entry '8169.' However since that entry was marked "declined," what is not a duplicate of the other entry is:

1. Detail I included exactly to help avoid it being 'declined' on how the feature can be sufficiently and yet minimalistly:

   - doable from the backend view ( ASCI and limited to 256 characters )
   - exposed at the UI view so users not wanting it are not visually burdened by it (as a user clicks on the 'favorite' star, show a text field with a grey transparent tip reading 'add an optional comment')
2. A detailed motivating use-case:

   - As I was reading:  '[Texturing Quadrics in JOGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911141/texturing-quadrics-in-jogl)' 
     I clicked on the star, and *really* wanted to add a quick note-to-self, "why" I clicked on it, e.g.:  *"with jogl now supporting evaluators/nurbs/quadrics, perhaps get around to evaluating camera remapping in gl"* . While that comment is obviously not relevant to others, *that's the point*. The comment captures for me the differential, specific hook inducing me to click it as a favorite

---

**Long-term usability gain to stackoverflow:** As I look over my page of favorites (esp whilst looking for something specific) such 1-liner comments would enable me:

- to make connections *between* the things that I've favorited across quarters past, based on my *now-current* sense of what I would use in the next few months
- to cull irrelevant favorites, which in-turn helps reduce the fear that just a browse through my favorites list while I look for something might induce my brain's (already nearly full) stack to overflow

Comment: Good idea - it would allow you to differentiate between those you want to bookmark for "posterity" and those you just want to be able to check back on in a couple of days.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate of the one mentioned. I'd really like to have the option to add a short note or tag about why I starred it. I use favorites to track canonical questions that I like to refer others to, and to track questions I am interested in following, and to track new activity in questions I've answered. The last case leads to some people having thousands of favorites. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/notify-us-when-the-question-has-been-edited-after-posting-an-answer